# echo back value in asp

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp-classic

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

**It should then echo just the hub.challenge value back, which confirms to Facebook that this server is configured to accept callbacks, and prevents denial-of-service (DDoS) vulnerabilities.**

What is the equivalent of "echo" in classic asp.
I thought it is response.write so I wrote the following code but its not working when I test it.

```
fbMode          = Request.QueryString("hub.mode")
fbChallenge     = Request.QueryString("hub.challenge")
fbVerify_token  = Request.QueryString("hub.verify_token")

Response.Write fbChallenge
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Response.Write.
I'm guessing your querystring param is blank.

Comment: @Efe the answer from Henrik is correct. Response.write is the analogue for Echo. Are you sure that block of code is reached?